# Is this code standard compliant or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14, c++98

So the code is

```
class A
{
public:
   int i;
   A(){
       i = 5;
   }
};
class B : public A
{
public:
   void someFunc();
};

class C
{
   A myObj;
public:
   void func(){
       B* foo = reinterpret_cast<B*>(&myObj);
       foo->someFunc();
   }
};
```

Assuming that classes will stay as they are and never change, is this use of reinterpret_cast correct(i think that it's not)? If not, which exact parts of C++ standard(you can use any edition) are violated here?

Comment: No, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you asking whether it is legal and well-defined to `reinterpret_cast` any pointer-to-`base` to pointer-to-`derived`, when the object _isn't_ a `derived`?

Comment: The question is mostly about the specific paragraph of the standard text that is violated. I know that this is most likely UB, i just want to know the exact reason with source

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit myObj is not of type B here

Comment: @Pavel: Indeed. It _isn't_ a `derived`.

Comment: Should the `reinterpret_cast` be a `dynamic_cast` instead?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `A` is not polymorphic.

Comment: If you have to ask you already have an answer: *don't do it*

Comment: I think if `someFunc` was `friend void someFunc(B*)` (and we called it like that), the above would be defined? (under layout compatible).  I suspect this being illegal could be a flaw in the standard, as are there implementations for which a non virtual method call is fundamentally different in a breaking way than a function call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your program does induce UB. §9.3.1/2:

> If a non-static member function of a class `X` is called for an object
>   that is not of type `X`, or of a type derived from `X`, the behavior is
>   undefined.

`A` is not of type `B` or a type derived from `B`.

Comment: Right. The `reinterpret_cast` is a red herring. OP has a `B*` to a `A` and tries to do stuff with it. Never going to work. (The irony is, in his example, it probably _will_ :P)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit .. should I explain why the cast itself is valid?

Comment: @Columbo if you can, do)

Comment: @PavelBeliy Well, I obey LRiO, but it's defined via §5.2.10/7.

Comment: @Columbo do you reference the C++98 standard here? i think they moved things around in C++11

Comment: @PavelBeliy No, I'm referencing C++14 (the latest revision), though this rule exists since C++98 with the same wording - but a different place.